# Laravel5, I like to place Event::listen() in a separate file, but the Event facade was unknown

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-facade

I would like to have a set of `Event::listen()`s in a separate file, this is what I have done so far.

*bootstrap/autoload.php*

```
...
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/listeners.php';
```

*bootstrap/listeners.php*

```
<?php

use \Event;

Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query) {
    dd($query);
});
```

The error is **class Event not found**

What is the right way for my requirement? I'm not sure creating a new .php file and require it from *bootstrap/autoload.php* is the right way for this requirement or not.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the Facades are not available in the bootstap, because the IOC 
Container of Laravel has not been create at this moment and so the Facades arent initialized yet.

In L5 the EventListeners have to be registered in the boot of the EventServiceProvider (app/providers).

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events

Comment: So, should I just define Event::listen() in the `boot()` method of the `EventServiceProvider` ?

Comment: yes, but for better organization i prefer to build single Eventhandler classes